# Windows Collation in Oracle

Tags: ssis

I am new SSIS and the package that i am building involves the use of Merge Join. Join is performed between a RAW File and Oracle Table. The `NLS_SORT` and `NLS_COMP` option for oracle database is `"BINARY"`. RAW File, by default picks up Windows Collation. What is the equivalent of Windows Collation in ORACLE? Will the above settings would work or some workaround is required, since i am not getting desired results from Merge Join. I had even used `SELECT.... ORDER BY NLSSORT(EmployeeName, 'BINARY_CI')`, but still getting wrong results. Do anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use Data Conversion element for both Sources,before Sort element. Choose  same data type for both columns NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP , now you can JOIN on new columns with new data types.

Some youtube example on [data conversion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzfZJlN4nzI#t=4m45s)